# Cassandra Node driver: TypeError: Object #<Metadata> has no method 'refreshKeyspaces'

Tags: node.js, cassandra

Getting the following stack trace:

```
TypeError: Object #<Metadata> has no method 'setCassandraVersion'
at getKeyspaces (/var/node/metrika/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/control-connection.js:272:21)
at /var/node/metrika/node_modules/cassandra-driver/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:13
at iterate (/var/node/metrika/node_modules/cassandra-driver/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
at /var/node/metrika/node_modules/cassandra-driver/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:29
at /var/node/metrika/node_modules/cassandra-driver/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
at /var/node/metrika/node_modules/cassandra-driver/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:723:17
at /var/node/metrika/node_modules/cassandra-driver/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
at /var/node/metrika/node_modules/cassandra-driver/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
at /var/node/metrika/node_modules/cassandra-driver/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
at /var/node/metrika/node_modules/cassandra-driver/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:269:32
```

What would be causing this?

Comment: Which is it, `refreshKeyspaces` or `setCassandraVersion`?

Comment: Can you specify when this error occurs, which driver version or how are you using it?